# Python pandas access to True and False values after groupby and size are applied

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column named diff. I am able to group this column and get the number of True and False occurrences in the data frame.

```
df.groupby('diff').size()
```

returns

```
diff
True    5101
False     61
dtype: int64
```

I want to access to the value of `True`, `5101`.

I have already tried

```
df.groupby('diff').size().loc['True']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `Series`, so `loc` should be omit:

```
s = pd.Series([5101, 61], index=[True, False])
print (s)
True     5101
False      61
dtype: int64

print (s[True])
5101
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
df_merged.groupby('diff').size().loc[True]
```

Explanation: note that

```
df_merged.groupby('diff').size().index
```

returns

```
Index([True, False], dtype='object', name='diff')
```

It's a bool `True`, not  a `"True"` like in a string !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `.loc` with `lambda`

```
s = df.groupby('diff').size().loc[lambda x :x]
```